# ICEpush 3.0.1 causes no response in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, icepush, icefaces-3

I have posted on both JBoss and Icesoft but to no avail.  I am hoping someone here can help.

I have a relatively complex EAR deployment, and one of the modules is a web app. It works great with ICEfaces 3.0.1. I have the interface working fine. However, if I add the icepush.jar and the web.xml entries the web app fails to respond to the browser request. The browser just 'spins' and never gets a response.

Is there some configuration that I can post to get some help with this, or is there some logging I could turn on to see what is happening?

Thanks.

```
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>icepush</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>org.icepush.servlet.ICEpushServlet</servlet-class> 
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>icepush</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>*.icepush</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Environment: 
Java 1.6.0_26 
JBoss 7.1.1 (standalone) 
ICEfaces 3.0.1 (Build number: 7, Revision: 28541) 
ICEpush 3.0.1 (Build number: 2, Revision: 28519)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue too. From my fidings I could see it only happens with jboss and when icepush is present.

In your standalone.xml put the the log level at INFO for javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle like this:

```
<logger category="javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle">
    <level name="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

I explained the root cause in the icesoft forums, here:
http://jforum.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/20819.page#74038